# Is looking angry/looks angry

Tags: present-tense

This sentence is from "Understanding and Using English Grammar" by Betty Schrampfer Azar.

"Right now I am looking at Janet. She (look) looks angry. I wonder what's the matter. She (have) has a frown on her face. She certainly isn't having any fun right now."

The correct answer is "looks angry" because I am not talking about her appearance. But if I was, can't I say "She is looking angry" if I am describing her appearance?

Comment: I don't see why not. _Looking angry_ is a continuing state just like _not having fun_.

Comment: It's not that you *can't* say "looking angry", but we just don't usually use the progressive with "look *adjective*".